# How to set margin only on all but first and last items in wrapping Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Say I have a wrapping list of items that goes over multiple rows. I want to then add a gap between all the items. However, I don't want to have a gap before the first item of each row, and no gap after the last item of each row.

You can accomplish this by having an explicit number of items per row, but I want the number of items per row to be dynamic.

It looks like this so far, but I haven't been able to figure out how to get it working with no margin on the sides.

```css
.a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: yellow;
}

.b {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
  <div class='b'>1</div>
</div>
```

Notice the space at the start of each row. I don't want there to be any space. Wondering how to accomplish that.

Same with vertical. I don't want a space at the top and bottom of the whole thing, just the space between the inner elements.

Comment: Why not tag 'css'?

Comment: Have you tried decreasing padding-left and padding-right of the parent container? or is it 0 already?

Comment: you could also make use of `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` css property and set the styles accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your list in a container div, give the list negative margins to offset the list item margins, and hide the overflow in the container:

```css
.c {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.a {
  margin: -5px;
}

/* your original CSS */

.a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: yellow;
}

.b {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='c'>
  <div class='a'>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
    <div class='b'>1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```